# Unknown block type "code", please specify a serializer for it in the `serializers.types` prop

Tags: next.js, sanity

I am currently working on my blogging website with Next.js and Sanity. I am trying to add custom code block in Sanity rich text using Code Input but encountering the following error:

**Unknown block type "code", please specify a serializer for it in the `serializers.types` prop**

Here is serializers.js

```js
  function BlockSerializer(props) {
    var node = props.node,
      serializers = props.serializers,
      options = props.options,
      isInline = props.isInline,
      children = props.children;
    var blockType = node._type;
    var serializer = serializers.types[blockType];

    if (!serializer) {
      throw new Error("Unknown block type \"".concat(blockType, "\", please specify a serializer for it in the `serializers.types` prop"));
    }

    return h(serializer, {
      node: node,
      options: options,
      isInline: isInline
    }, children);
  } // Low-level span serializer
```

Can anyone please help how can I add the serializers prop in the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using types beyond the defaults (i.e., `code`), you'll need to specify how they are to be serialized. Your front end doesn't know how to handle the `code` type. There's an example under the [Usage](https://github.com/sanity-io/block-content-to-react#usage) section of the repo readme.

Comment: Sir, I got your point but can you please tell me how can I add "code" type in the BlockSerializer function mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this same issue while trying to create a custom code type for my Sanity content with React Portable Text in AstroJs(so contextualize this for your Next.JS project). For this particular error: **"Unknown block type "code", please specify a serializer for it in the serializers.types prop"**

Like stated in a previous answer, the problem is that you are trying to render content with a type that is different from the default types. If you want to do this you need to use a serializers.unknownTypes prop like so:

```
    <PortableText
                    content={content}
                    projectId={projectId}
                    dataset={dataset}
                 serializers={{ unknownType: ({ node }) => {
                            if (node._type === "code") {
                              console.log(node);
                              return (
                                <div className=" border-blue-500">
                                  <pre data-language={node.language} className="bg-black w-fit">
                                    <code className="text-green-500">
                                      {node.code}
                                    </code>
                                  </pre>
                                </div>
                              );
                            }
                          }

}}


                
                  />
```

Hope this helps!, read more from here (for dealing with unknown types check out the propTypes section of the documentation): https://github.com/sanity-io/block-content-to-react#usage